# Why is there no unsafe_any_cast for std::any?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, stdany

My local version of the Boost headers (1.56.0) has the following functions defined in `boost/any.hpp`, copied verbatim:

```
// Note: The "unsafe" versions of any_cast are not part of the
// public interface and may be removed at any time. They are
// required where we know what type is stored in the any and can't
// use typeid() comparison, e.g., when our types may travel across
// different shared libraries.
template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType * unsafe_any_cast(any * operand) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    return &static_cast<any::holder<ValueType> *>(operand->content)->held;
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline const ValueType * unsafe_any_cast(const any * operand) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    return unsafe_any_cast<ValueType>(const_cast<any *>(operand));
}
```

Even though the online documentation does not even acknowledge their existence: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any/reference.html

I noticed that [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) also does not seem to have support for an unsafe any cast.

**Why does the C++17 standard not introduce `std::unsafe_any_cast`?**

If an exact reason cannot be found (or if it was simply never proposed), what would be the most compelling arguments to not provide unsafe access to the value stored in an `std::any` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::any` is a **type-safe** container for single values of any type.

Note from the comment in the snippet you posted, that Boost's `unsafe_any_cast` is **not** part of the public interface. It is an implementation detail, and is not meant to be used by the end-user. That is why it is not mentioned in the documentation.

Promoting it to the public interface would break the purpose of having a type-safe container in the first place.

Comment: I do not agree to the last statement, std::any does have use-cases such as calling the contained objects constructor or type-safe copying. Providing an unsafe cast would not break these advantages. (The lack of unsafe_cast is a reason I still stick  to boost::any)

Comment: @ViktorSehr Thanks for your comment. Please note that the last paragraph is not the main point in the answer. The main point is that the function `unsafe_any_cast` is not part of the public interface of Boost, which means it may not be available on future versions. The last paragraph adds a view from a design perspective: Having a *public* function whose sole purpose is *breaking the class' contract* is not a good design decision. If you need an unsafe cast, `std::any` (Or `boost::any`, for that matter) is probably not the way to go.